# good way to delete huge number of emails from exchange server before downloading to Microsoft Outlook Client?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

There are huge number of alerting emails sent to my email. I need to delete the huge number of alerting emails with certain subject line in Outlook 365 server before downloading to the Microsoft Outlook Client. It is crashing the Outlook Client. Is there a way to do that? Please advice. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you contact your support to block these emails instead? It's better to save the server from receiving these emails in the future.

Comment: I created the rules to delete the mail with the specific subject line, but still failed to work. Does the rule only work before receiving the mail in the mailbox? Now all the alert emails (massive number) are in my mailbox and I have a very hard time to delete them.

Comment: Yes, the rules are working for the future emails you are about to receive, however i believe there is an option to apply the rules to the current mailbox

Comment: This may help [run rules for existing mails](http://m.windowsitpro.com/outlook/q-how-can-i-run-outlook-rules-manually)

Comment: I am unable to see this option in Office365 Outlook Web Application. I am not the administrator

Answer (score 0):

Switch your Outlook to Online Mode (disable Exchange Cached Mode). Restart Outlook, create a rule as needed and run it. After the rule completes, enable Cached Mode back to download mailbox contents.